# symfony 3 url issue

Tags: php, symfony, url

Hi I'm coming for a very simple question (I think) but i didn't found the answer or a similar case.
I'm using symfony 3 and trying to build a second menu for my administration pannel.

However, I have a problem about how I have to declare the relative url in my "href", For my main menu i used to do like this

```
{{ url ( 'admin' ) }}
```

and it worked. The fact is that now I have subfolders and many levels in my url.

The url i try to reach is myapp/admin/gameadmin, this url work when I'm going on it but when i try to put it in 'href' I have an error message which says that the route is not working.

i declared it like that ->

```
{{ url(admin/gameadmin) }}
```

I tried with different character -> admin:gameadmin, admin\gameadmin ... etc and with path instead of url i don't know if it's not the good way to declare it or if I have a problem with my controllers.

In my bundle it's organised like that :

```
   ->Controllers(folder)
        ->admin(folder) (You can also find my main controllers on this level)
           ->admingamecontroller (Where the page I try to reach is  routed)
```

I hope i gave you all the informations, thank you for your help and sorry for my english !

Answer (score 2):

The `url` parameter is not the the url per se (ie: admin/gameadmin), this is the route name, defined in your `routing.yaml` file, or in your controller annotation.

If your action is something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/gameadmin", name="gameadmin")
 */
public function gameAdminAction()
{
    ...
}
```

Then, to generate the route, you have to do this:

```
{{ url('gameadmin') }}
```

By doing this, all the links on your website will be up to date if you change the gameadmin url, as long as you don't change the route name.

I suggest you to read this documentation on the Symfony website: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html

Edit: As pointed by [user254319](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422586), if you're not using annotations, you'll have to edit your `routing.yaml` config file.

```
gameadmin:
    path:       /admin/gameadmin
    controller: App\Controller\Admin\AdminGameController::gameadminAction
```

The route name is the yaml key: `gameadmin`.

Related Symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

Comment: Just to complete the answer. At first url twig extension generates [absolute urls](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#url). Relative urls you can be generated by [path extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path). Second: Not everyone is using annotations. This link can help more: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

Comment: Thank you ! I know that it was easy but I was unable to find the good answer, i forgot that URL was using the name and not the route.